# Read and output a txt file to a desired format

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a text file:

```
- the quick brown
- fox jumps over
- the lazy dog
```

The structure of each line is `[hyphen] [space] [text]`.

Then I wrote this:

```
echo "$(cat file.txt | tr "\r\n" ";" | tr -d "-")"

//  the quick brown- fox jumps over- the lazy dog
```

How can I format the text like below? I want to add a space before the hyphen but cannot figure out the proper method.

```
 the quick brown - fox jumps over - the lazy dog
```

Comment: Is that odd symbol that looks like an ice cream cone at the start of `echo "$(cat file.txt | tr "\r\n" ";" | tr -d "-")"` really part of your input or is just lines that start with `-` as you show under "I have a text file"?

Comment: @EdMorton it is, I need to have an emoji at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` to concatenate the lines with `-s`, using a space character as delimiter provided by `-d`, then use `sed` to replace the first hyphen:

```bash
paste -sd ' ' file.txt | sed 's/-//'
```

```
 the quick brown - fox jumps over - the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{sub(/-/,"")} {printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=" "} END{print ""}' file
 the quick brown - fox jumps over - the lazy dog
```

Answer (score -3):

To format the text as you've described, with a space before each hyphen, you can modify your existing command slightly. Here's how you can do it:

```
echo "$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ - /g' file.txt | tr -d "-")"
```

This command will give you the desired output:

```
 the quick brown - fox jumps over - the lazy dog
```

Comment: That command can't produce that output as the `tr -d "-"` would delete all `-`s.